# How to have auto suggest / auto complete for the spring config file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bean id="reservation" class="com.youtube.Reservation" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="train" ref="trainobject" />
    <property name="bus" ref="busobject" />
</bean>


<bean id="busobject" class="com.youtube.Mode">
    <property name="name" value="KPN" />
</bean>

<bean id="trainobject" class="com.youtube.Mode">
    <property name="name" value="Shatabdi" />
</bean>
```

My XML looks like above. I need auto suggest for creating this spring configuration. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, proper `beans` tag would be useful.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Please refer to [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#xsd-config) regarding this topic.